# Check if a collection of ranges is within, and covered another range

Tags: javascript, range

I have a range that is defined by `start` and `end`, and an array of ranges in `collection`

```
var start = 10;
var end = 60;

var collection = [
    {start:5, end:15},
    {start:15, end:30},
    {start:45, end:60}
];
```

How to check if ranges in `collection` are within `start` and `end` and covered the whole range?

Comment: Have you tried anything to solve this problem? Looping over the collection seems like a good start.

Comment: Familiarize yourself with [how to access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/4642212) and use the available [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Methods_of_the_Object_constructor) and [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods) methods.

Comment: You can use any loops or you can use `filter` like this: `const newCollection = collection.filter(c=>c.start>=start && c.end <= end)`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by :

- Expanding the main range into array of numbers.
- Loop collection, expand also those into array of numbers.
- Check if the array is within the range, if it's within range remove those numbers from the main array,  if not return false (array to check is not witin range)
- After the loop, check the length of main array, if it's more than 0 return false (array collection is within range, but doesn't cover the main range). If it's 0 meaning the collection array is within range, and cover the whole main array.

When googling I found the use of lodash. here is the code in my function :

```
let parentRange = _.range(start, end + 1); // Expand into array of numbers

for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
    let rangeToCheck = _.range(collection[i].start, collection[i].end + 1); //Also expand into array of numbers
    if (_.difference(rangeToCheck, parentRange).length === 0) { // Check if collection range is within parent range
        _.pullAll(parentRange, rangeToCheck); // Remove the numbers from parent range that matches collcection range
    } else {
        return false; // Not within parent range
    }
}

// Check if parent range has values left
if (parentRange.length != 0) {
    return false; // Collection ranges does not cover parent range
} else {
    return true; // Collection ranges is within parent range, and cover the whole numbers
}
```